# Modeling of inherited entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity called Type, type have data1, data2 and data3 as attribute.
I'd like to have Type1 which extends Type and Type2 which extends Type too

For exemple

```
Class Type
{
    private $data1;
    private $data2;
    private $data3;   
}

Class Type1 extends Type
{
    private $data4;
}

Class Type2 extends Type
{
    private $data5;
}
```

I'd like to get this in my Symfony entities and this must works with Doctrine.

Comment: What's the table level strategy you are willing to adopt? One table per class? One table for all classes? And what data will serve as the PK?

Comment: I think the better solution is to have a table per class. The PK will be an id in the Type class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your example, use the following Doctrine annotations:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type_Disc", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"type1" = "Type1", "type2" = "Type2"})
 */
Class Type
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="data1", type="integer")
    */
    private $data1;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="data2", type="integer")
    */
    private $data2;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="data3", type="integer")
    */
    private $data3;   
}

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
Class Type1 extends Type
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="data4", type="integer")
    */
    private $data4;
}

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
Class Type2 extends Type
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="data5", type="integer")
    */
    private $data5;
}
```

As extra information, you need something called a "discriminator column" (here called `Type_Disc`), so the ORM can discriminate on the type of entity. You don't have to map it to an entity value, but it has to exist in your schema. In the discriminator map you tell what values the classes will be mapped into the discriminator column. For instance, in this example `Type1` will be mapped to `type1` in `Type_Disc`. You could also use numbers, in which case it would be something like this:

```
 /**
 ...
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type_Disc", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({0 = "Type1", 1 = "Type2"})
 */
```

Please keep in mind the schemas have to be something like this, using a SQL pseudolanguage:

```
CREATE TABLE Type1 (
    id int not null primary key autoincrement(1,1), /*This has to be defined somewhere in your entity*/
    Type_Disc nvarchar(50) not null,
    data1 integer not null,
    data2 integer not null,
    data3 integer not null
)

CREATE TABLE Type2 (
    id int not null primary key,
    data4 integer not null,
    foreign key (id) references Type1(id)
)

CREATE TABLE Type3 (
    id int not null primary key,
    data5 integer not null,
    foreign key (id) references Type1(id)
)
```